# how to disaply dinstinct values in a table

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have this table,

```
Date        Service     Main Plate  Tithe   S.School / Class    Other   Total
2018-11-25  English     20520         2500   20000                0     43020
2018-11-25  Chichewa    50000         1500       0                0     51500
2018-11-18  English     51000            0       0             1500     52500
2018-11-18  Chichewa    10533         5000   21000                0     36533
```

and I run this code,

```
SELECT date, sum(total) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date, total FROM offering) as totals;
```

and I have this view,

```
date            sum(total)
25 Nov, 2018    183553
```

i want to save the view in table and have rows of different dates. Please anyone, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query to select the data.

```
SELECT date, sum(total) 
  FROM offering
GROUP BY date
```

Of course you could save this in a different table, but usually this is not required: You can use a view which you can later on query like a table:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT date, sum(total) as total
  FROM offering
GROUP BY date
```

Later on you can query the view instead of the table:

```
SELECT date, total
  FROM yourView
```

If you really want to save the query result in a new table you would first have to create the table and subsequently insert the selected result into the new table. Here is something on creating a new table: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp 
And more on how to insert the selected values into the new table:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me, ,it is what i was looking for.